# Восстановление удалённых данных с ext4

Tags: ext4, ubuntu

Я неудачно пошутил, а шутка была не правильно понята. Друг всё же выполнил:

```
rm -rf /*
```

Может кто-то подскажет методы восстановления данных с ext4? (Дело было под ubuntu 11.10.)

Answer (score 1):

Из-под винды по диску пройти R-Studio - на выходе будет много файла - не по названиям, а по номерам - придется разбираться, но если действительно НАДО игра свеч стоит

Answer (score 1):

Почти наверняка файлы уже не восстановить: пока система была в работе они могли быть переписаны новыми данными. Можно попробовать утилиту [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) для восстановления особо ценных данных (потребует времени).

Answer (score 1):

попробуй через консольное приложение testdisk ... он восстанавливает с оригинальными названиями файлов и папок